# Conditional Port Redirection on Local Machine Ubuntu iptables

Tags: iptables, redirect, port

I am new to this community and also to the tool I want to use, namely `iptables`, so please bear with my incompetence ^_^

Anyway, my situation is as follows:

1. I have a private LAN with private IP addresses.
2. The LAN is connected via a router to the network of my organization, which has a fixed IP address range.
3. This network, in turn, is connected to the internet via a gateway.
4. In my private LAN , I am running a server listening at port `A`.
5. It accepts all requests from all computers in my private LAN at port `A`.
6. It is a TCP server which operates in request/response mode, i.e., I need communication to and from it.
7. It is not accessible from anywhere outside of my private LAN.
8. The operating system is Ubuntu 16.04, `iptables` is installed.

I can easily configure my router to forward all incoming TCP connections to a port `B` to port `A` of my server. This would mean that anyone from the outside, from both the organization's network and the internet, could connect to my router's IP address port `B` and would be forwarded to my server port `A`. However, I only want that users in my organization's network are allowed to do so. For general users from the internet, it should not be possible to access my server.

What I want to achieve with `iptables` on my server is.

1. My private LAN behaves as before. All processes on the computers in my LAN can still connect to my server using its private IP address and port `A`.
2. Users in my organization's network (identified by an IP address range or subnet mask) can access the IP address of my router and port `B` in order to use my service, their packages are forwarded to my server and its port `A`.
3. Users who are neither in my private LAN nor in the organization's network should not be forwarded, they are not to connect to my precious server.
4. If a computer in my private LAN tries to access the server using port `B`, that should be OK and is acceptable, i.e., we can redirect anybody accessing port `B` except someone coming from the outside internet.

Now I have never used `iptables` before and I am not even even sure whether this can be done with it, although I think it probably can be done. I have seen a few examples, but they do not seem to do what I want and I am not sure whether I understand them sufficiently well to not break something by playing around.

Many thanks,
  Thomas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your LAN has 192.168.0.0/24 and your organization network has 172.16.0.0/24, your router has 192.168.0.1 (on eth1) and 172.16.0.1 (on eth0) addresses, and you want to access your server over 192.168.0.2:80 or 172.16.0.1:8080
In order to forward the packets, you'll need to add `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in /etc/sysctl.conf

```
#!/bin/bash

iptables -P INPUT DROP # if no rule match, drop the packet
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT # router can access everything

iptables -A PREROUTING -s 172.16.0.0 -d 172.16.0.1 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT 192.168.0.1:80 # destination nat with ACL

iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT # only accept established connections from LAN to router

iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT # established connections
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT # LAN to ORG or INET
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0-s 172.16.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT # this rule comes after the dnat one, so destination already changed

iptables -A POSTROUTING -i eth1 -s 192.168.0.0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.1 # source nat
```

You might have to play with iptables and customize to your needs.
What you need to know is : yes, you can do all you want with iptables.